# Excel If formula to vba

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, vba, microsoft-excel-2013

I have this formula which checks a cell to see if its a 6,2,a, or b, in which case the word cash is written.

```
=IF(OR(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("6",M2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("2",M2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("a",M2)),ISNUMBER(SEARCH("b",M2))),"cash","")
```

I would like to incorporate it into a macro but although I can get it to run for one cell, I need for it to check the entire column, not it just changes every instance to cash...not good for my other columns

This is what I've tried so far:

```
 Dim score As Integer, result As String
    score = Range("M2").Value

    If score = 6 Then
        result = "Cash"
    Else
        result = "fail"
    End If

    Range("n2").Value = result

End Sub
```

How do I get this to run through the entire column rather than entire workbook? I've tried changing the range to "M2:M10" but this didn't work. I need for it to run the entire column no matter how long.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: your question isn't really clear, please post some sample data and desired output.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to loop through the range using a range

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScoreIt()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("M2:M10")
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If myCell = 6 Or myCell = 2 Or myCell = "a" Or myCell = "b" Then
            myCell.Offset(, 1) = "Cash"
        Else: myCell.Offset(, 1) = "fail"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Edit `myRange` to whatever range you want.

---

Basically the `if` statement in VBA works differently than the `if` function. With the function it's

```
IF(OR([this,that,the other]),Then,Else)
```

Whereas the VBA `if` is more like

```
[IF this] OR [IF that] OR [IF the other] Then, Else
```

Based on your description of your formula, your formula could be written

```
=IF(OR(M2=6,M2=2,M2="a",M2="b"),"cash","fail")
```

Which is more similar to the VBA.

But, what your formula is actually doing is searching for values, so the VBA would be more like this

```
Option Explicit

Sub ScoreIt()
    Dim myCell As Range
    Dim myRange As Range
    Set myRange = Range("M2:M10")
    For Each myCell In myRange
        If InStr(1, myCell, 6) > 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myCell, 2) > 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myCell, "a") > 0 Or _
        InStr(1, myCell, "b") > 0 Then
        myCell.Offset(, 1) = "Cash"
        Else: myCell.Offset(, 1) = "fail"
        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Worked like a charm :)